# Rails query one model based on the lack of an associated model with conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I've always had a problem querying based on more than one associated model, and querying based on the lack of an associated model.

So I'm trying to implement a way to mark messages as read or not for each specific user.  These are the models I'm working with:

```
class Stock < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :stock
  has_many :message_viewings
end

class MessageViewing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :message
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :message_viewings
end
```

My goal is to find all Stocks with Messages that lack MessageViewings by a specific User.  I want this information so I can indicate to users whether or not they have unread messages.  None of my attempts are worth mentioning so far.

**UPDATE**

Further searching led me to a nicely documented gem that almost did what I wanted: https://github.com/ledermann/unread .  Taking the query listed there and modifying it a bit I've come to this new query which seems to get what I want done, though I'm not sure as to how efficient it may be:

```
Stock.joins(:messages).joins("LEFT JOIN message_viewings ON \
  message_viewings.message_id = messages.id AND \
  message_viewings.user_id = #{User.sanitize(current_user.id)}").where(
  "message_viewings.id IS NULL")
```

Comment: I've updated my answer, hopefully it helps you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
Stock.joins(messages: :message_viewings).where("message_viewings.user_id != ? or message_viewings.user_id is null", current_user.id)
```

Just make sure the current user is set.

#### Updated Code

If you want all stocks that that don't have a message_viewing belonging to the current user then do:

```
@user = # code to retrieve user
Stock.joins(:messages).joins("LEFT JOIN message_viewings ON message_viewings.message_id = messages.id").where("message_viewings.user_id != ? OR message_viewings.id IS NULL", @user.id)
```

I think there's a mistake in the code you wrote, since if user_id in the message_viewing is present then the message_viewing's id is not going to be null.

I would probably put that code in the stock model:

```
# stock model
def self.join_message_viewings
  joins(:messages).joins("LEFT JOIN ... ")
end

def self.unread_by(user_id)
  .where("messages_viewings.user_id != ... ", user_id)
end

# query
Stock.join_message_viewings.unread_by(@user.id)
```

You could make the final query into one method if you prefer.

Comment: This is almost what I'm looking for, but I do need to include Messages that have no message_viewings by any user as well.

Comment: Try the updated code, although for me it worked better when I used includes instead of joins.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, I managed to find a relevant gem with a similar purpose as my objective: https://github.com/ledermann/unread .  It was documented nicely enough for me to put together a query that seems to have worked.  As I'm a new user, I can't answer my own question so I've edited yours.

Comment: Update your question with the code and let's see if we can simplify it.